# AWS: Switch an Aurora MySQL RDS Instance from multi-az to single-az

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have an Aurora MySQL RDS deployment with a writer and reader with multi-az enabled.
I'm having to look at trying to cut costs on AWS and one of the things that I want to downgrade is the multi-az to single-az.
Is it possible to do this with an Aurora MySQL instance/cluster?
The setting isn't available from the modify page.

If it's not possible does this mean I need to recreate the DB with multi-az disabled?
Would that mean the endpoint changes? This would be a problem for me as many applications use the current endpoint so if that was to change everything would go down until all the applications were updated.
Is there a way to do this while maintaining the original endpoint?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not possible to downgrade a multi-AZ Aurora deployment to single-AZ. You will have to create a new Aurora cluster and use DMS with ongoing replication to migrate to it.

To avoid downtime, you should create hosted zone in Route53 and define dedicated subdomains for db endpoints, e.g. db-master.yourdomain.com => CNAME [original Aurora endpoint]. Using the defined subdomains in your application configuration for db access allows for updating the db endpoint at once in Route 53. E.g. when DMS finished the migration, just update CNAME values.

Comment: Please note that costs improvement you mentioned has another cost - availability of your RDS instance in case of failure or maintenance. Multi-az automatically and quickly switches to a replica in this case and is highly available, but single-az will be down until the instance is fully restored. In other words you save costs by moving to single-az but lose in availability of your RDS instance.